# Adding a big static library as a cocoapod or directly adds ALL object files to resulting binary because of -ObjC linker flag

Tags: objective-c, xcode, build, linker, objective-c-category

**PROBLEM: Linking with my library adds 2MB to binary.**

I am trying to distribute my own static library on iOS. My library depends on KSCrash and ProtobufObjc pods. Pods are compiled in their own targets and later as a static libs (libabc.a) are linked to target application - that is usual procedure for working with cocoapods. There is a flag '-ObjC' passed to linker, that causes ALL object files from KSCrash and Protobuf to be pulled into resulted app binary. My code has files that contain only categories, so I cannot remove this flags without consequences. Pulling this 2 libs adds up to 1.5MB to resulted app binary size. If I link without '-ObjC' added size is about half less - because dead_stip flag, which, I suppose, works only if there is no '-ObjC', 'load_all' etc flags.

**Question: How can I make 'dead_strip' or any other mechanism work, while not loosing Objective-C categories?**

**notice 1**: I cannot afford stripping symbols because I need on-device symbolication.

**notice 2**: Regeneration of protobuf code with LITE flag doesn't reduce size, I think I have to use C++ version to make it work.

Answer (score 2):

The `-force_load` linker flag should solve your problem. From the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1490/_index.html):

> -all_load forces the linker to load all object files from every archive it sees, even those without Objective-C code. -force_load is
>   available in Xcode 3.2 and later. It allows finer grain control of
>   archive loading. Each -force_load option must be followed by a path to
>   an archive, and every object file in that archive will be loaded.

If I understood your problem correctly, you should point `-force_load` to your library archive to include all categories. I don't quite understand why you can live with not loading everything from your dependencies, but it may not be essential to help out...

Comment: Ok, lets put it this way: 
I link with one big library. This library has among others categories-only files. I don't need all library classes. There is dead_stip flag that strips all unused classes from my app, but I also include -ObjC to force load all symblos. As a result dead_strip doesn't works.

Comment: Can you further describe how the project is structured? Is it… a) App-Target directly links to [libabc.a, KSCrash, ProtobufObjc], or b) App-Target links to [libabc.a], and this links to [KSCrash, ProtobufObjc], or totally different?

Comment: If you familiar with CocoaPods - application depends on some cocoapods. It looks like in a workspace there 2 projects - application and Pods. Pods project builds a static library for every pod I depend on. After building all static libraries it merges them into one big static library. After merging it Application project builds  application sources and then links to this big-all-pods-together libarary with -ObjC flag included.

Comment: Just refreshed my CocoaPods knowledge and I think it works slightly different. It doesn't actually build libs for every pod, it just organises every pod's files in a separate group/folder. It then builds one big library from all the pods' source files. Technically, there aren't any separate libs at any stage, so you cannot set separate linker flags either. That said, my approach won't work... I think the only way to keep the unused code out of the final product is to get rid of the source files in Xcode, so you may have to change the podspecs (`s.source_files` key) of the external libraries.

Comment: Actualy it builds each pod separately with flags provided in .podspec for each pod. So you can provide separate set of flags to each pod via .podspec. There are separate lib for every pod. You can easily see it if after making pod install and looking at Pod project's targets - there are target for every pod and they build static libs.

Comment: Maybe I was using an old/outdated version, I just grabbed a CocoaPods sample project. There was only 1 target for all pods. So you could try adding the `-force_load <path_to_your_lib.a>` to the app target? (...and removing the `-ObjC` flag from the app target)

Comment: Yes, I can, but how its going to reduce target app size? In KSCrash there are only-categorie-files and 'normal' files. I can't link it without -force_load. And I can't link it with -dead_strip. Force loading adds ALL object files to binary and stops dead_strip from functioning.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42489/discussion-between-hagi-and-andrei-shender)